# How can I make an "item" disappear when the player once stands on it's position? C#

Tags: c#, console, console-application, game-development

I make this little Escape Room game where the player needs to collect a key for getting out of the room. How can I make the Key disappear whenever the player steps on it? This is my code so far. I know I haven't used any methods because I haven't learned it in university so far.. So it would be great if anyone has a simple solution or help for me. Thanks in advance! <3

```
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo consoleKey;

        int XPositionCursor = 5;
        int YPositionCursor = 5;

        int MapWidth = 20;
        int MapHeight = 20;

        char Wall = '█';
        bool GameOver = true;
        char Key = '@';
        char Character = 'H';





        int[,] MapGenerationArray = new int[MapWidth, MapHeight];
        Random RandomKeyCoordinate = new Random();
        Random RandomDoorCoordinate = new Random();




        #region Instructions
        Console.WriteLine("Wähle eine Breite für dein Spielfeld:");
        string MapWidthString = Console.ReadLine();
        MapWidth = int.Parse(MapWidthString);
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Wähle eine Höhe für dein Spielfeld:");
        string MapHeightString = Console.ReadLine();
        MapHeight = int.Parse(MapHeightString);
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine($"Dein Spielfeld wird {MapWidth} x {MapHeight} groß sein!");
        Console.ReadLine();

        #endregion


        Vector2 KeyCoordinate = new Vector2();
        KeyCoordinate.X = RandomKeyCoordinate.Next(1, MapWidth - 1);
        KeyCoordinate.Y = RandomKeyCoordinate.Next(1, MapHeight - 1);


        Vector2 DoorCoordinate1 = new Vector2();
        DoorCoordinate1.X = RandomDoorCoordinate.Next(0, MapWidth);
        DoorCoordinate1.Y = RandomDoorCoordinate.Next(0, 0);

        bool PlayerIsOnKeyPosition = XPositionCursor == KeyCoordinate.X && YPositionCursor == KeyCoordinate.Y;
        bool PlayerCarryingKey = false;

       do
        {
            #region Map

            Console.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 0);
                Console.Write(Wall);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapWidth; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, MapHeight);
                Console.Write(Wall);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
                Console.Write(Wall);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < MapHeight; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(MapWidth, i);
                Console.Write(Wall);
            }

            #endregion


            Console.SetCursorPosition(XPositionCursor, YPositionCursor);
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.Beep(200, 100);
            Console.Write(Character);


            if (PlayerIsOnKeyPosition)
            {

                PlayerCarryingKey = true;
            }

            if (PlayerCarryingKey == true)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition((int)DoorCoordinate1.X, (int)DoorCoordinate1.Y);
                Console.Write(' ');

            }
            else
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition((int)KeyCoordinate.X, (int)KeyCoordinate.Y);
                Console.Write(Key);


                Console.SetCursorPosition((int)DoorCoordinate1.X, (int)DoorCoordinate1.Y);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write(Wall);
                Console.ResetColor();


            }



            #region CharacterMovement

            consoleKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

            Console.Clear();

            switch (consoleKey.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    YPositionCursor--;
                    break;


                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    YPositionCursor++;
                    break;


                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    XPositionCursor--;
                    break;


                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    XPositionCursor++;
                    break;
            }

            if (YPositionCursor < 1) { YPositionCursor = 1; }
            if (XPositionCursor < 1) { XPositionCursor = 1; }
            if (YPositionCursor >= MapHeight - 1) { YPositionCursor = MapHeight - 1; };
            if (XPositionCursor >= MapWidth - 1) { XPositionCursor = MapWidth - 1; };

            #endregion


        } while (GameOver == true);

    }

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code... a guess. You check `bool PlayerIsOnKeyPosition` outside the loop - check it inside the loop so it gets updated?

Comment: Thanks! So i added it inside the game loop and it works better now, but still, whenever I move the player away from the key position they key and the door are still there ..

Answer (score 0):

As @doctorlove wrote, you are calculating whether player has a key before your main loop (do/while).
But you should do this inside main loop, every time player changes his position.
Replace line `if (PlayerIsOnKeyPosition)` with this `if (XPositionCursor == KeyCoordinate.X && YPositionCursor == KeyCoordinate.Y)`.

P.S. Good idea is to use methods (functions) to split code into smaller chunks :)